# Brush strokes disappear when exported

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, brush

I am trying to use a ’watercolour‘ brush stroke behind my text in two different colours which I have done successfully. When I export my image to PNG, the brush strokes are appearing on the small preview image:

[image: Preview image]

However, when I open the PNG, the strokes have disappeared:

[image: PNG]

Is there something I need to do to be able to view these in large when exported?

Comment: Is the layer perhaps a dimmed template?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please have a look at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Also, I removed one of two apparently identical images from your question. Please check that everything is correct and [edit] again if appropriate.

Comment: Much more information about file construction would be necessary to supply an answer. Color mode. Layer construction. Transparency/Blend modes.